# How to train tensorflow model when some outputs do not matter?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

For example i want to train tensorflow model which has 2 outputs. If first output is 1 then i look at the second output, but if the first output is 0 then second output doesn't matter. Is there a way in tensorflow to set the error on second output to 0 when the first output is 0 or I have to specify all the outputs. Sorry if that is dumb question but I'm new to tensorflow.

Better example. I want to check if there is a dot in the feeded image. My model has 5 outputs. First one predict if there is a dot in the image(values from 0 to 1).The next 4 outputs shows where is that dot in the image (position, width and height). So if I feed a model with an image without dot what should i put in the output. [0,anything,anything,anything,anything] or [0,0,0,0,0]. And if the first one, how to do it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this phrase a bit "..to set the error on second output to 0..." ??
Also, please see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your loss so that it does not consider the second portion of output if the first one is zero. If the image does not have a dot in it you may use an arbitrary number for the last 4 numbers, because if the first number is zero they are not considered in your loss. I hope this helps.

More readings: Object detection and the idea of anchor boxes in the Faster-RNN paper may help to understand how this might work: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf